# Warning on method chains

Tags: java, android, method-chaining

Honestly I'm not sure what I am looking for or how to bring it up, but I give it a try:
Sometimes in a class that contains method chains (like builders) we need to warn developer to call a method at the end of chain to take effect, for example in android:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
```

If you do not call `commit()` or `apply()` after putting values in `Editor`, you get this warning :

> SharedPreferences.edit() without a corresponding commit() or apply()
>   call.

I'm trying to implement similar behavior for my class, I mean show warning if a specific method not called at the end of the chain, Any clue or solution will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in the case of your SharedPreferences example is a [Lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29) check and is not a behaviour of the class itself.
You can implement your own custom checks in Android Studio by following this guide http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

Comment: Is it possible to do it with java annotations?

Comment: I've never implemented it myself. You should take a look at the guide.

Comment: No worries, if it answers your question please accept it.

Comment: Sure, Let me try it first.

Answer (score -1):

What you looking for is a Android Code Design Pattern which is called - `Builder Design Pattern`.

> Builder pattern is a creational design pattern it means its solves problem related to object creation.It is also very oftenly used in android development.

[Try and Learn pattern here - Medium](https://medium.com/@ajinkyabadve/builder-design-patterns-in-java-1ffb12648850)

Comment: Maybe I didn't asked well! I AM familiar with builder pattern, My question is about warning the developer if a specific method is not called